# Can schtask specify a task to run regardless if a user is logged in on local machine / Windows 10 Home

Tags: windows-10

I've created the following task but at the appointed time it doesn't run.
As a test `run.bat` contains a copy command to copy single file.

```
schtasks /create /tn solo /rl HIGHEST /f /ru local_username /rp user_password /st 15:45 /sc DAILY /tr "cmd f:\sch\run.bat"
```

`local_username` is a Windows 10 user account that is not signed in at `/st`
I am running Windows 10 Home.

Comment: Does `local_username` have the same `f:` drive mapping? Drive mappings are per-user; for this reason I always recommend UNC paths instead of mapped drive letters.

Comment: that worked. thank you. Not because local_username didn't have the same drive mapping but because local_username needed a "share" for the script to run.